# Replacing sbt-native-packager with sbt-docker in Scala Play

Tags: scala, docker, playframework

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#The-Native-Packager

Is it possible to replace this plugin with `sbt-docker` ?

Comment: Do you really need to replace it? SBT Native Packager also supports docker...